# How to have task in VS Code run in current terminal not a new pane?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have this task,

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run Jest on Current File",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "yarn",
      "options": {
        "env": {
          "CI": "true"
        }
      },
      "args": ["test", "${file}"],
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "shared",
        "showReuseMessage": false,
        "clear": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[This shows what I mean by second terminal pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErcEE.png)

I would like for this to run in the current terminal I have open instead of opening a new one that would close when I press any other button. It would be nice to not have to worry about a different terminal pane specifically for tasks. The task pane doesn't use my color theme, therefore it's harder to see what has passed or failed as well.